# Is php 7.2 mandatory for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, php-7.2

I was told that a current wordpress version requires php 7.2 or newer. Is that true? Or to put it another way: to what extent is it mandatory to use php 7.2 for Wordpress? Are there any safety reasons? Isn't php 7.0 enough? Wordpress reads that they require php 7.2. > [Wordpress Recommendations](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/)

Answer (score 3):

No, [the article you linked](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/) clearly states the following:

> We recommend your host supports:
>
> - PHP 7.2 or greater
>
> If you are in a legacy environment where you only have older PHP or MySQL versions, WordPress also works with **PHP 5.2.4+** and MySQL 5.0+, but these versions have reached official End Of Life and as such may expose your site to **security vulnerabilities**.

As you can see, WordPress will work even with PHP 5.2 and PHP 5.3, etc., but it is **recommended** to use recent versions instead.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But my question was: isn't php version 7.0 enough? Why shall I use php 7.2 at this moment? Or why php 7.1. For me it is clear, that I use php 7.0. But not why I should use php 7.1 or php 7.2. Do you or does other has some apt reasons?

Comment: If you desire, you can look through [the changelog](https://secure.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php) to see how many security relevant vulnerabilities have been patched since the release of 7.0. In general, it's recommended to stay with the latest stable release.

Comment: Thank you David, especially for the changlog-Link! I am not sure but not every bugfix has automatically a security reason... And 'stable' does this means security patches?

Comment: I ask because quite a lot of server which work with longterm operating systems has not the possibility to upgarde any php version immediately. So are they automatically insecure?

Comment: It's difficult to make a blanket statement here. Some servers implement so-called "backport" patches, which apply security fixes, but don't add new functionality. I would highly recommend you to ask this question specifically in [security.se].